# Can step function state machines have multiple event schedules

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I currently have a step function that calls an orchestration lambda on a cron event schedule which runs once a day.  The lambda processes data for all of my customers.  I want a second cron event schedule that runs hourly for my priority customers. What is the best way to accomplish this?  The existing one is ok to run for all customers once daily as it is now.  The new one would need to run hourly for a set of customer id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [EventBridge](https://console.aws.amazon.com/events/home) (CloudWatch Events) you can create multiple rules to start executions of the same Step Functions state machine with different inputs and schedules. If your state machine can be reused for both sets of customers, you can create a daily and an hourly rule that triggers the state machine with input indicating which customers to process.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/create-eventbridge-scheduled-rule.html